# centos 6.3 bug command[cp]

Tags: linux, cp, bugs

echo "aaa" >abc.1.txt
echo "bbb" >abc.2.txt
cp abc*

## linux no error

bug  same command [ cp abc.1.txt  abc.2.txt]

cp abc.*  =  cp abc.1.txt  abc.2.txt

why?

Comment: Can you add some formatting to clear up exactly what you typed? What happened, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Are you aware that `*` is handled by the shell before `cp` is called? You might think there can be no copying because you gave no destination, but `cp` doesn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a bug, is the intended behaviour for shell variable expression.

As ulrich-schwarz has correctly stated, variable expansion happens before your `cp` command is executed. You have two files that meet the condition of the expresion `abc*`, so it is expanded to their full names.

Indeed, if you create a third file `abc.3.txt` it will try to use the three files as parameters for `cp`.

You can verify all this if you set the debug (`set -x`) mode before running the command, which shows you each real command as it is executed, after expansion happens. Remember to disable the debug mode (`set +x`) once you finish.

```
$ echo "aaa" >abc.1.txt
$ echo "bbb" >abc.2.txt
$ ls
abc.1.txt  abc.2.txt
$ set -x
$ cp abc*
+ cp abc.1.txt abc.2.txt
$ cat abc.2.*
+ cat abc.2.txt
aaa
$echo "ccc" > abc.3.txt
+ echo ccc
$ cp abc*
+ cp abc.1.txt abc.2.txt acb3.txt
cp: target «acb3.txt» is not a directory
$ cat abc.2.*
+ cat abc.2.txt
aaa
$ cat abc*
+ cat abc.1.txt abc.2.txt abc.3.txt
aaa
aaa
ccc
$ set +x
+ set +x
```